# Match URL with regex

Tags: regex, testing, cypress

I am having problems matching the following URLs with Cypress intercept() using regex. What am I doing wrong?

```
cy.intercept('GET', /https:\/\/mysite\.me\.com\/pages\/[^\/]+[0-9](?=\/$|$)/, { fixture: 'pages.json' }).as('getPage');
```

Matching URLs:

- https://mysite.me.com/pages/1
- https://mysite.me.com/pages/804
- https://mysite.me.com/pages/134568

Non-matching URLs:

- https://mysite.me.com/pages/?something=something
- https://mysite.me.com/pages/1234/something
- https://mysite.me.com/pages/something

I would ultimately like to use the regex with an env variable but first things first.

```
cy.intercept('GET', `${Cypress.env('API_PATH')}/pages/[^\/]+[0-9](?=\/$|$)/`, { fixture: 'pages.json' }).as('getPages');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regex looks unnecessarily complicated, try to simplify it to something like:

```
/\/pages\/[0-9]+[/]?$/
```

that will match both:

```
/pages/1234
```

and:

```
/pages/1234/
```

---

```
[^\/]
```

You don't need `\` because `/` has a different meaning inside a character class.

```
(?=\/$|$)
```

Ok, so the `/` at the end is optional. This is more readable: `[/]?`, or even `\/?`.

And I don't think you need to be as explicit as mentioning the base url in the pattern.

Comment: 'That regex looks unnecessarily complicated,' sounds about right. :) Thank you for your help, `/\/pages\/[0-9]+[/]?$/` worked great!